# "Save Page" or "Download save" window extends beyond bottom of screen (OS X)

Tags: macos

When saving page or downloading file, the"save" window extends below the bottom of the page, i.e., I cannot access the "save" or "cancel" buttons.

I believe that this has happened since upgrading to Yosemite, but not certain. This does not happen with other browsers.

Anybody else seeing this?

Comment: You didn't say which browser, but I'd guess Chrome...

Answer (score 1):

If you Cmd/Shift/drag from either side of the window, it will resize equally from all sides & allow you to reach the part you can't see.

Alternatively, switching to & from fullscreen should resize it too.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to save look to the right of the where you would name your document, there is an up arrow, press that twice and the save option will appear by highlighting the full document.